# iOS 15.4.1 iPhone 13 with FireFox: Cannot decode data

Tags: ios, firefox

I’m trying to track a package shipped to me via USPS.  At usps.com I can’t receive tracking info.  The tracking url always returns an odd error page: [image: odd error page].

Therefore, I just attempted browsing usps.com.  USPS.com returns this screen: [image: this screen with “cannot decode raw data” and “NSURLErrorDomain”]

I’ve learned that this type of error usually has to do with gzip.  However,
I only have iZip installed.  And I don’t have server access into usps.com to attempt any of the server fixes I’ve read about.

Tracking packages is important.   Please help me access usps.com.

P.s. using Firefox Daylight 98.2 (8475)
P.p.s hope this is asked in the correct forum

Comment: Firefox has gzip builtin to handle compressed http requests, it doesn’t depend on installed utilities. Does it work if you use another browser or access the URL via curl?

Comment: @nohillside, thank you for letting me know about Firefox’es gzip.  No, opening that usps.com tracking url returned same error page in both Duckduckgo and Safari browser; my VPN was enabled during those quick tests.  Sry, do not have/know-about curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooh, sigh, I had to pause/disable my VPN (Virtual Private Network) to enable posting my question here.

And, after pausing/disabling my VPN, again, usps.com works just fine.  Package tracked!

---

**It appears that usps.com never works, for me at least, when my VPN is enabled.**